# Asm comments not being skipped over

Tags: assembly, gcc, comments, gnu-assembler

When trying to compile the following program stub:

```
;put 1 into accumulator register
mov     $1,     %eax
```

I get an error on:

```
$ gcc d.s
```

> d.s: Assembler messages:
> d.s:1:
> Error: no such instruction: `put 1 into accumulator register'

Why doesn't the assembler skip over the comment, or is there something I'm doing wrong here to insert in a comment?

Comment: You have to use `#` or `//` or `/*...*/`, as `;' is a comment in Intel syntax, while GCC uses  AT&T syntax

Comment: @JCWasmx86 thanks, that fixed it. Want to put it into an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it?

Comment: No, I don't think such a comment is worth an answer, as it is neither good nor even reaches the guidelines for answers

Comment: @JCWasmx86: `//` and `/* */` comments won't work in a `.s` file, only in a `.S` where GCC will run the C preprocessor on it before assembling.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just tried with both `.s` and `.S`. Working with both

Comment: @Waqar: Are you putting the comment at the start of the line? `/` works as a line-comment character in GAS, but something like `mov $1 + 2, %edi     // do the math at assemble time` won't assemble with GAS.  Even that will assemble with `clang`, though; are you on a Mac where `as` is actually clang / llvm-as in disguise, and `gcc -static foo.s` is actually `clang`?  On my GNU/Linux desktop, `clang -static foo.s` will assemble a file with `//` not at the start of a line.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. The `//` or `/*` style comments don't work if they are on the same line as assembly code. But they work on separate lines. And no, I am on Linux with `gnu-as`